# Javascript executes in wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have to use a website (ticket system) with a select element, that contains currently 9994 options. This is not changeable and has to be accepted as is.

When I work on a ticket on that website, I have to select a specific entry from that select. I have a total set of around 30 entries I have to choose from. I don't care for the other entries.

The required 30 entries can be seperated into 3 patterns for a RegEx filter.

So I decided to use Greasemonkey+JQuery to clean that select element up, so I can easily and quickly find the entries I am looking for.

The filtering is working fine, but it takes time (of course it does...), so I want to show a little "please wait" div as overlay, while the filter is running to give some kind of user feedback.

---

On page load I create the overlay:

```
$("body").append('<div id="pleaseWaitOverlay" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; background-color: rgb(255,255,255);">HALLO WELT</div>');
$("#pleaseWaitOverlay").hide();

//This is the select element with the "few" entries
fixedInReleaseElement = $('select[name=resolvedReleasePath]');

//Adding buttons to filter for one of the patterns are also added on page load
```

If I press on one of the filter buttons, the following function will be called:

```
function filterFixedInReleaseList(filterFor) {
    $("#pleaseWaitOverlay").show();
    //$("#pleaseWaitOverlay").show().delay(500).show(); - or as hack without success...

    var pattern;

    //Based on "filterFor" parameter, the required pattern will be used.
    // [MORE CODE]

    fixedInReleaseElement.find("option").each(function() {
        var currentOption = $(this);
        if (pattern === "") {
            currentOption.show();
        }
        else {
            if (pattern.test(currentOption.text())) {
                currentOption.show();
            }
            else {
                currentOption.hide();
            }
        }
    });

    //$("#pleaseWaitOverlay").hide();
}
```

But somehow, the filter will take place and THEN the overlay will be shown.

Please note:

- Currently, the .hide() lines are commented out, as the popup would not be shown (or rather seen) at all with those lines executed.
- The .show().delay(500).show() was a try to kind of hack it, but it changed absolutly nothing.
  I also tried fixedInReleaseElement.find("option").delay(1000).each() without success. I appears that delay does not work at all?

So, what is the problem here? Why is the overlay shown after the filter has been executed?

The complete Greasemonkey script can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/auafMSR1

Comment: have you considered http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/? I have an autofill for placenames with 15000 placenames and it responds within 0.5seconds.

Comment: Yeah, or Chosen : http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: A better understanding how JS event loop works will help you to avoid these kind of problems in the future. I feel this is a good explanation about it. http://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A browser tab only has one thread, that is shared between JavaScript and UI updates. Thus, if your JavaScript is running, the UI is not getting updated.

So, this:

```
function doSomethingLongWithOverlayWrongly() {
  $x.show();
  doSomethingLong();
  $x.hide();
}
```

will set appropriate attributes of `$x` to be hidden, then do something long, then set the attributes back; and when `doSomethingLongWithOverlayWrongly` (and all the computation that is in its future) finally exits and relinquishes control of the executing thread, the browser will take note that some attributes were changed, and repaint if necessary (but it's not, since the element was set to invisible, and is now still set to invisible).

Do this instead:

```
function doSomethingLongWithOverlayCorrectly() {
  $x.show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    doSomethingLong();
    $x.hide();
  }, 0);
}
```

This will set `$x` to be hidden, then schedule a timeout, then exit. The browser takes a look, sees a repaint is in order, and shows your overlay. Then the timeouted function gets run, does something long, and sets `$x` to be hidden again. When it exits, the browser takes another look, sees that a repaint is required, and hides your overlay.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! It works now as expected. Also I know what I did wrong.